# Why is the ideal $\langle x-2,x+3\rangle$ in $Z[x]$ prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Why is the ideal $\langle x-2,x+3\rangle$ in $Z[x]$ prime?

I know it is equivalent to show the quotient is an integral domain, but I am having trouble showing this, or showing it is prime directly.

This question was already asked here: [Show the ideal $(x-2,x+3)\subset\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is prime but not principal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3707212/show-the-ideal-x-2-x3-subset-mathbbzx-is-prime-but-not-principal)

But there isn't an accepted answer (or even an answer demonstrating why the ideal is prime)

Comment: the generating elements have degree 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to first rewrite $\langle x-2,x+3\rangle$ as $\langle x-2, 5\rangle$ and then "substitute" $y=x-2$ to get the ideal $\langle y,5\rangle$ in $\mathbb Z[y]$. This has an easy description: it's an ideal of all polynomials in $y$ with constant term a multiple of $5$.

Now checking that this ideal is prime in $\mathbb Z[y]$ is equivalent to checking that $\langle 5\rangle$ is prime in $\mathbb Z$, since the constant terms aren't affected by any other terms when we add or multiply.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the substitution technique/trick, is the idea behind it that Z[x] = Z[x-2] = Z[y]? If so, then this makes sense. And do you mean to say polynomials in y with constant term divisible by 5? Since I suppose y itself belongs to the ideal

Comment: @trynalearn More formally, the map $p(x) \mapsto p(y+2)$ defines an isomorphism from $\Bbb Z[x]$ to $\Bbb Z[y]$.